# `org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Premature end of chunk coded message body: closing chunk expected` on Spring Boot Get Request

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm currently learning to create a rest API using Spring Boot and Spring Data JPA. The idea is to create an API for a library application which allows `Borrower`s to request book loans that are then to be approved by the `Librarian`s.

Among the app's many Entities, I have two which I named `Author` and `Book`. The `Author`s can have zero to many `Book`s, while a `Book` can have one to many `Author`s. So if a new `Book` were to be added to the database, an account with a `Librarian` role should first add the `Author`(s) before adding the `Book`. The plan is for the JSON file for the POST request for adding the new `Book` to have to include an `authorCodes` array which corresponds to the already-added `Author`'s codes.

As the `Author` and the `Book` entities form a Many-To-Many relationship, I created a bridge table named `BookAuthor` in my database, but instead of bridging them by their primary keys (which are of the data type UUID), I opted to use their `AuthorCode` and `BookCode` instead (which are also constrained in the database to be unique), as they are a more natural identifier compared to UUIDs. In the entities' code the relevant properties are connected with `@ManyToMany` annotations.

Below are the source code of the aforementioned tables and entities:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Author(
    Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT NEWID() PRIMARY KEY,
    Code VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    FirstName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    MiddleName VARCHAR(255) NULL,
    LastName VARCHAR(255) NULL,
    BirthDate DATETIME2 NOT NULL,
    DeceasedDate DATETIME2 NULL,
    CreatedDate DATETIME2 NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(),
    ModifiedDate DATETIME2 NULL
);
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Book(
    Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT NEWID() PRIMARY KEY,
    Code VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    Title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    Description VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PublishDate DATETIME2 NOT NULL,
    PublisherCode VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    Stock INT NOT NULL,
    IsDisabled BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    CreatedDate DATETIME2 NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(),
    ModifiedDate DATETIME2 NULL
);
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.BookAuthor(
    Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT NEWID() PRIMARY KEY,
    AuthorCode VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    BookCode VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    CreatedDate DATETIME2 NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(),
    ModifiedDate DATETIME2 NULL
);
GO
```

`AuthorCode` and `BookCode` are generated in the relevant Services.

For the entities:

**Author**

```
@Entity
public class Author {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    private String id;
    @NaturalId
    private String code;
    private String firstName;
    private String middleName;
    private String lastName;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinTable(
            name = "BookAuthor",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "AuthorCode", referencedColumnName = "Code"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "BookCode", referencedColumnName = "Code"))
    private Set<Book> books;
    private Date birthDate;
    private Date deceasedDate;
    private Date createdDate;
    private Date modifiedDate;


//getters and setters
```

**Book**

```
@Entity
public class Book {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    private String id;
    @NaturalId
    private String code;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "books", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE} )
    private Set<Author> authors;
    private String publisherCode;
    private Date publishDate;
    private Integer stock;
    private boolean isDisabled;
    private Date createdDate;
    private Date modifiedDate;

//getters and setters
```

The APIs for inserting a new `Author` works fine, and so does for inserting a new `Book` with the `Author`s already inserted:

**InsertAuthor**

```
POST http://localhost:8081/author
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Bearer ...

{
  "firstName": "Ron",
  "birthDate": "1992-12-13"
}
```

**InsertBook**

```
POST http://localhost:8081/book
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Bearer ...

{
  "title": "Lorem Ipsum",
  "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.",
  "publishDate": "2012-10-10",
  "publisherCode": "PUBL-0",
  "stock": 5,
  "authorCodes": ["AUTHOR-0","AUTHOR-1","AUTHOR-2"],
  "isDisabled": false
}
```

The backend also successfully inserts the required data into the bridging table, `BookAuthor`, so I thought I've been using `@ManyToMany` correctly.

A problem arises when I tried to get the list of all the inserted books, though:

```
GET http://localhost:8081/book
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Bearer ...
```

Instead of getting an array of `BookResponse`s, I got this error:

```
org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Premature end of chunk coded message body: closing chunk expected
```

Below are my Controller methods:

```
@PostMapping("/author")
    public ResponseEntity<AuthorResponse> insert(@RequestBody @Valid InsertAuthorCommand command){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(authorService.insert(command), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

@PostMapping("/book")
    public ResponseEntity<BookResponse> insert(@Valid @RequestBody InsertBookCommand command){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(bookService.insert(command), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

@GetMapping("/book")
    public List<BookResponse> getAll(){
        return bookService.findAll();
    }
```

And the Services:

**BookService**

```
public List<BookResponse> findAll() {
        return bookRepository
                .findAll(Sort.by(Sort.Direction.ASC, "Code"))
                .stream().map(book -> {
                    BookResponse response = new BookResponse();

                    response.setTitle(book.getTitle());
                    response.setCode(book.getCode());
                    response.setDescription(book.getDescription());
                    response.setAuthors(book.getAuthors());
                    response.setPublisherCode(book.getPublisherCode());

                    return response;
                }).toList();
    }

@Transactional
    public BookResponse insert(InsertBookCommand command) {
        Book newBook = new Book();

        newBook.setCode("BOOK-"+bookRepository.count());
        newBook.setTitle(command.getTitle());
        newBook.setDescription(command.getDescription());
        newBook.setStock(command.getStock());
        newBook.setPublishDate(command.getPublishDate());
        newBook.setCreatedDate(new Date());
        newBook.setDisabled(command.isDisabled());
        newBook.setPublisherCode(command.getPublisherCode());

        bookRepository.save(newBook);

        Set<Author> authors = command.getAuthorCodes().stream().map(authorRepository::findByCode).collect(Collectors.toSet());
        for(Author author: authors){
            author.getBooks().add(newBook);
            authorRepository.save(author);
        }

        BookResponse response = new BookResponse();
        response.setTitle(newBook.getTitle());
        response.setDescription(newBook.getDescription());
        response.setCode(newBook.getCode());
        response.setAuthors(authors);

        return response;
    }
```

**AuthorService**

```
@Transactional
    public AuthorResponse insert(InsertAuthorCommand dto) {
        Author author = new Author();

        author.setFirstName(dto.getFirstName());
        author.setMiddleName(dto.getMiddleName());
        author.setLastName(dto.getLastName());
        author.setBirthDate(dto.getBirthDate());
        author.setDeceasedDate(dto.getDeceasedDate());
        author.setCode("AUTHOR-" + authorRepository.count());
        author.setCreatedDate(new Date());

        authorRepository.save(author);

        AuthorResponse responseDto = new AuthorResponse();

        String fullName;
        ...

        responseDto.setFullName(fullName);
        responseDto.setCode(author.getCode());
        responseDto.setBirthDate(new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy").format(author.getBirthDate()));
        responseDto.setDeceasedDate(
                author.getDeceasedDate() == null ?
                        null :
                        new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy").format(author.getDeceasedDate()));

        return responseDto;
    }
```

I tried simplifying the `BookService` so that it immediately returns `Iterable<Book>` without having to map the results to `List<BookResponse>`, but the error persists.

The error also does not appear when I removed the properties which are annotated with `@ManyToMany`. Which seems to mean that I have used the annotation incorrectly, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

When debugging the code, I noticed that the values from the `Book` entity are retrieved successfully, and that the exception appears after `bookService.findAll()` returns the values. But I am not at all familiar with Spring's source code so I do not know what to look.

Could someone let me know what I'm doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wasn't immediately obvious from the error message alone, but it seems to be a problem of infinite recursion. The problem is solved by using the `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference` annotations as explained in [this blog](https://www.keenformatics.com/how-to-solve-json-infinite-recursion/).

`@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference` respectively specify which item of the relationship shall and shall not be serialised, so I decided for the Book items (`Set<Book> books` in the `Author` class) to not be serialised because I only need the `Book` items to show their `Author`s, and do not wish  for each of the `Author`s included in the `Book` JSON returned to show their `Book`s.